# Program that prompts the user to input 5 integers and outputs these integers in reverse order

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, iteration, reverse

I need help with this Python program.

With the input below:

```
Enter number: 1​
Enter number: 2​
Enter number: 3​
Enter number: 4​
Enter number: 5​
```

the program must output:

```
Output: 54321​
```

My code is:

```
n = 0
t = 1
rev = 0
 
while(t <= 5):
    n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    t+=1
    a = n % 10
    rev = rev * 10 + a
    n = n // 10
print(rev)
```

Its output is "12345" instead of "54321".
What should I change?

Comment: From your request is not clear what's the correct output for this example: if input = `"12340"` the correct output is `"04321"` or `"4321"`?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
t = 1
rev = ""
 
while(t <= 5):
    n = input("Enter a number:")
    t+=1
    rev = n + rev

print(rev)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
x = [int(input("Enter a number")) for t in range(0,5)]
print(x[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be an easier way if you create a list and append all the values in it, then print it backwards like that:

```
my_list = []
while(t <= 5):
    n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    t+=1
    my_list.append(n)
my_list.reverse()
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    print(my_list[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
n = 0
t = 1
rev = []
 
while(t <= 5):
    n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    t+=1
    rev.append(n)
rev.reverse()
rev = ''.join(str(i) for i in rev)
print(rev)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Maintaining a numerical context: use "10 raised to t" (10^t)

This code **is not very different** from your solution because it continues to work on integer numbers and return `rev` as an integer:

```
t = 0
rev = 0

while (t < 5):
    n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    # ** is the Python operator for 'mathematical raised to'
    rev += n * (10 ** t)
    t += 1
print(rev)
```

`(10 ** t)` is the Python form to do `10^t` (10 raised to t); *in this context it works as a positional shift to left*.

### Defect

With this program happens that: if you insert integer `0` as last value, this isn't present in the output.
**Example**: with input numeric `12340` the output is the number `4321`.

### How to solve the defect with zfill() method

If you want manage the result as a string and not as a integer we can add zeroes at the start of the string with the string method `zfill()`.
In this context the `zfill()` method fills the string with zeros until it is 5 characters long.

The program with this modification is showed below:

```
NUM_OF_INTEGER = 5
t = 0
rev = 0

while (t < NUM_OF_INTEGER):
    n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    rev += n * (10 ** t)
    t += 1
# here I convert the number 'rev' to string and apply the method 'zfill'
print(str(rev).zfill(NUM_OF_INTEGER))
```

With previous code with input `"12340"` the output is the string  `"04321"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    n = int(input("How many number do you want to get in order? "))

    list1 = []

    for i in range(n):
        num = int(input("Enter the number: "))
        thislist = [num]
        list1.extend (thislist)

    list1.sort()
    print ("The ascending order of the entered numbers, is: " ,list1)

    list1.sort (reverse = True)
    print ("The descending order of the entered numbers, is: " ,list1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).